# perl script to find matching lines in two files

Tags: perl, string-matching

I have two files that look like (below) and want to find the fields from the first in the second file, but print every field of the second.

```
#rs116801199 720381
#rs138295790 16057310
#rs131531 16870251
#rs131546 16872281
#rs140375 16873251
#rs131552 16873461
```

and

```
#--- rs116801199 720381 0.026 0.939 0.996 0 -1 -1 -1
#1 rs12565286 721290 0.028 1.000 1.000 2 0.370 0.934 0.000
#1 rs3094315 752566 0.432 1.000 1.000 2 0.678 0.671 0.435
#--- rs3131972 752721 0.353 0.906 0.938 0 -1 -1 -1
#--- rs61770173 753405 0.481 0.921 0.950 0 -1 -1 -1
```

My script looks like:

```
#! perl -w

my $file1 = shift@ARGV;

my @filtered_snps;
open (IN, $file1) or die "couldn't read file one";
while(<IN>){
    my@L=split;
    #next if ($L[0] =~ m/peak/);
    push @filtered_snps,[$L[0],$L[1]];

}
close IN;

my $file2 = shift@ARGV;

my @snps;
open (IN, $file2);
while (<IN>){
    my@L=split;
    foreach (@filtered_snps){

        if (($L[1] eq ${$_}[0]) && ($L[2] == ${$_}[1])) {

            print "@L\n";

            next;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting no output, when I should be finding every line from file 1. I've also tried grep with no success.

Answer (score 0):

In first `while` you are assigning to wrong array, you meant `@L` here.

Then you have pretty different strings in your first array (from first file) and in  other. Try to print them both out in your for-iteration. You'll see they can't match.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hash table of the items from the first file, then iterate over the second file and check if that rs-name exists... I'm also confirming that the number matches the name.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
my $regex = qr/#.* *(rs\d+) (\d+) *.*/;

open my $file1, '<', shift @ARGV;
while (<$file1>) {
    my ($name, $num) = $_ =~ $regex;
    $hash{$name} = $num;
}
close $file1;

open my $file2, '<', shift @ARGV;
while (<$file2>) {
    my ($name, $num) = $_ =~ $regex;
    print if (exists $hash{$name} and $hash{$name} = $num)
}
close $file2;
```

Comment: The thing is I'm sure all the names from file1 exist in file2. I just need to pull out the lines in file2 that have those rsIDs and numbers. File2 is much larger than file1 and has additional rsIDs that I don't want.

Comment: That's exactly what my script does... It prints lines from file2 that exist in file1. It will not print lines from file2 that are not in file1.